# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table in sqlite in Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have tried lots of time, but could not get how to get this problem, everything ok on SQL Broswser, SQL query run without getting but when run the problem, than getting

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table
```

. Please tell , whats going on here.

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private Context mycontext;

private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.tosts.yummi/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "hotss";
private static String DB_TABLE = "kathas";

public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private int id;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
private String TAG = "horror";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.mycontext = context;
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if (dbexist) {
        // System.out.println("Database exists");
        opendatabase();
    } else {
        // System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        createdatabase();
    }
}

public void createdatabase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if (dbexist) {
        System.out.println(" Database exists.");
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copydatabase();
            //myDataBase.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkdatabase() {
    // SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
    boolean checkdb = false;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE) != null;
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }

    return checkdb;
}

private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);
    Log.d(TAG, "COpt Test->"+"InputStream->"+myinput+"--?"+outfilename+"---"+myoutput);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];// transfer byte to inputfile to
                                    // outputfile
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myoutput.flush();// Close the streams
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();
}

public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
    // Open the database
    String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null) {
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);
    //onCreate(db);
}

// This will return a cursor containing database records
public Cursor data() {

    Cursor c;
    c = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

   public List<String> getAllKatha(int category){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        //List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM kathas where category =" + category;
        Log.d(TAG, "--->>>"+selectQuery);
        myDataBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
                //ids.add(cursor.getString(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        myDataBase.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }
```

I am getting like this on log cat:

```
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: kathas (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM kathas where category =3
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527):     at com.nepal.nepalisexstories.database.DatabaseHelper.getAllKatha(DatabaseHelper.java:139)
12-23 19:37:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(1527):     at com.nepal.nepalisexstories.DisplayTitle.onCreate(DisplayTitle.java:70)
```

**Actually doing this on MainActivity.java**

```
titles = db.getAllKatha(category); ///(DisplayTitle.java:70)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: in Databasehelper class, i declared in question.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quiet explicit, the Table "kathas" has not being created, and that's because you have nothing in the "onCreate" method of the SQLiteOpenHelper, and something went wrong in the method you are using to create the database, that is a terrible implementation on Database Creation, you should make use of the SQLiteDatabase argument passed in the onCreate method of your SQLiteOpenHelper, also I noticed that you are using the onUpgrade method which calls the "onCreate" that doesn't have anything, so in case you updated the database nothing actually happened.

Comment: yeah i know, but have already created database which is in assets folder, I am following just like this: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: That's a terrible implementation sir, you should stick to Android Standards specially because that method do not allow you to upgrade your schema, look at the comments on the post you got it, people brings that up...

Comment: @PrAndroid Read my answer - you are explicitly dropping the table - of course it won't be found when you execute your query

Comment: @MartinCazares and ALeks Thanks for that, but same method actually work, this type of errors comes, when i am trying to put ads on this apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your `onCreate` method, but that's not really that bad, because you're copying an existing database.  What's really bad, is that in your `onUpgrade` method you're executing:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kathas
```

Then you're calling your `onCreate` which does nothing.

Obviously, your table is not found - because you're explicitly dropping it.